# Remove "hole" in array after remove item

Tags: java

I need to delete some objects from an array if they meet a condition.

After removing the object from the array I need the array to have no "holes", meaning I need to shrink the array: not the array size, but reducing the number of objects it contains.

It's okay if there are null values at the end of the array after removing objects.

Which would be more efficient?

1. Copying the array into new array
2. Iterating over the array and shift the elements over the "hole" created by removing an object

I *must* use an array, I cannot use a `List` implementation.

Comment: Create a new array if you don't want to use an arraylist.

Comment: Defragmenting the existing array in place is more efficient concerning runtime, but then you'll have trailing empty slots. If that's OK for you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an ArrayList, this will allow you to dynamically change the size of your structure.

Comment: If you think about it, arrays are a "block" of assigned memory so even if you shift the data down there will still exists a null element at the end. So as you suggested you need to create a new smaller array and copy the items into it. The elegant Arrays util class may help http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_arrays.htm

Comment: Its OK that all my element at the end is null because at the beginning after define the array size all the elements inside is null, i just need to ensure that this array wont have any holes in the midlle

Comment: ok, well the most efficient way then is not to copy the whole array, but just copy the values with i> the index removed to i-1 . If you get me. There is no point in copying all the value where i<index removed as these are unaffected by the operation. So like your second option, but use an array copy function so you don't have to shift the data. Use Arrays.copyOfRange()

Comment: BTW, i need to ensure first the the null is in the middle of the array and not the null at the end (if there is no null in the middle) ?

Comment: not sure I follow you now! Well if the null is at the end then yes you won't need to shift, but surely you know this given that you know the index of the point that is being removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use ArrayList yuor solution is fine. But instead of copying your array, create a new empty one with the size of your array and then populate it in a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can swap deleted element with the last element and make something like `size--`

2) If you can't swap you have to use `System.arraycopy(...)` method multiple times to copy parts of array to new array.

```
public static Object[] deleteElement(Object[] oldArray, int position) {
    Object[] newArray = new Object[oldArray.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, position);
    System.arraycopy(oldArray, position + 1, newArray, position, newArray.length - position);
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirements,

> i need that my array will be without any "holes" so i need to "shrink" that Array,

you **must** create a new array and move the remaining objects to it.  Arrays are a fixed-size construct.  You cannot "shrink" an array.  You can only allocate new memory and move the elements to the new array.

EDIT:  You should alter your question to include the information about allowing `null` at the end of the array.  In that case, moving the elements back 1 index would be better since it eliminates memory allocation (which is expensive) and will have on average n/2 operations (assuming random removal) as opposed to n.

Comment: This question screams homework, and this is the best answer to learn from. The reason why you are restricted to using Array is because your professor/teacher would like you to problem solve instead of using an implementation that is already there.

Comment: That's why i think the best option is to shift all the elements after the null back

Comment: @user2214609:  The way you stated your question implies that would leave "holes" at the end.  If you can have null values at the tail end, then shifting all elements from n to n-1 back one index would be preferable in terms of performance -- however, it is NOT preferable in terms of "correctness."

Answer (score 1):

Both of your solutions are O(N) complexity, except the first one require another O(N) memory space. So the second one is slightly better if you really required to work on Array.

If you're working on an array of element that require frequent add and remove in the middle, I would suggest you use Linked-List implementation, so that it can give you constant time of adding and removing any element in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example using `System.arraycopy`:

```
    Integer[] i1 = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    Integer[] i2 = new Integer[4];

    // Copy everything, except the third value of i1:
    System.arraycopy(i1, 0, i2, 0, 2);
    System.arraycopy(i1, 3, i2, 2, 2);

    for (int j : i2)
    {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudocode

- Step 1: Find all the objects from the array that match whatever you want it to match and overwrite them with a unique value (for example: if your array only contains integers 0 or higher, overwrite the ones you want to remove with -1)
- Step 1.5: keep a counter of the AMOUNT of removes you did
- Step 2: Create a new array with the size of (oldarray.size - counterFromStep1.5)
- Step 3: for each non-empty element in oldarray THAT IS NOT (the remove integer), add it to new array